# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_work_faranesh`.`learnings`

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

hello i use this migrate and see this error

```
Schema::create('learnings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('course_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_work_faranesh`.`learnings` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter tab
le `learnings` add constraint `learnings_course_id_foreign` foreign key (`course_id`) references `courses` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

and course migrate

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');   
    });
```

Comment: Make sure id in courses table is of the same type as course_id in learnings (unsigned bigInt).

Comment: Whats your `courses` migration?

Comment: @kopz i add course migrate...to top

Comment: @TalhaF. i add course migrate...to top

Comment: Check the type of id in courses in your database. You also did not specify your Laravel version. course_id and user_id to $table->integer('')->unsigned();

Comment: not work    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_work_faranesh`.`learnings` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter tab
le `learnings` add constraint `learnings_course_id_foreign` foreign key (`course_id`) references `courses` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create migration like this:

First create Courses, and after that Learnings.

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');   
        });


Schema::create('learnings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Because you use unsigned twice for one column.

Comment: not work ... error   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_work_faranesh`.`learnings` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter tab
le `learnings` add constraint `learnings_course_id_foreign` foreign key (`course_id`) references `courses` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: I updated code, and please first create Courses, and after that, Learnings table.

Answer (score 1):

You can set foreign keys only in tables that already exist. Try this:

```
    Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    });
    Schema::table('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

And:

```
        Schema::create('learnings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('course_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('learnings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```